# meaning: Mr. Just About

Tags: vocabulary, jokes, names, word-play

Does "Mr. Just About" make sense as a nickname for someone who does not care about precision?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Why do you ask; where have you seen this? Nicknames don’t really have rules governing them, although this one seems just fine.

Comment: Mr Approximate, Miss Near-enough-will-do